# resetting a cumulative total based on a minimum value and indicating with a flag in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

reaching out as I am completely stuck.

I have a set of data where each row is an earning amount and is the primary key is a sequence number, so for example see here: [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/47aa4/4)

I need to (1) create a flag that is equal to '1' to indicate when the cumulative total reaches a minimum value, such as 50. And then (2) reset that cumulative total to 0 and pick it back up on the next sequence.

My attempt is below and also in the SQLfiddle, but it isn't in a great place.

For the "new_cumulative_total" column, I would expect 50 on the second row, and then 58 on the third row, 5 on the fourth row, and then 29 on the last row.

For the "ready for payout" column, I would expect a "1" any time the new_cumulative_total is greater than or equal to 50 and a "0" otherwise.

I know there's probably some window function magic to be done here, but regrettably I'm not skilled enough yet to do this. Could anyone advise? Thank you so much in advance!

```
with details as (

select
*,
sum(earning) over(order by sequence asc) as cumulative_total,
case when sum(earning) over(order by sequence asc) >= 50 then 1 else 0 end as ready_for_payout
from running_total_reset_example

)

select
*,
case when ready_for_payout = 1 then 0 else cumulative_total end as new_cumulative_total
from details
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *in the question*.

Comment: Can you explain why to expect 50 on the second row, 58 on the third row, 5 on the fourth row, and **29** on the last row? I though it should be **24** on the last row. Here is my modification to your code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/47aa4/17

Answer (score 0):

I have written the below code in SQL server management studio and was able to get the desired results.

```
begin
    create  table #tbl1 (sequence int, earning int, cumulative_total_1 int, cumulative_total_2 int)
    insert into #tbl1 select sequence, earning, 0, 0 from running_total_reset_example

    declare c1 cursor for (select sequence, earning from running_total_reset_example)
    declare @sequence int = 0, @earning int=0, @cumulative_total_1 int=0, @cumulative_total_2 int=0, @sum1 int = 0, @sum2 int = 0
    open c1
    fetch next from c1 into @sequence , @earning  
    while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    begin   
        set @sum1 = @sum1 + @earning
        set @sum2 = @sum2 + @earning
        if @sum2 >= 50 
            begin
                    set @sum2 = 0
            end
        Update #tbl1
            set cumulative_total_1 = @sum1, cumulative_total_2 = @sum2
            where [sequence] = @sequence
        fetch next from c1 into @sequence , @earning
    end
    close c1
    deallocate c1
    select sequence, earning, cumulative_total_1, cumulative_total_2, 
    (case cumulative_total_2
        when 0 then 1
        else 0
     end) as ready_for_payout
    from #tbl1
    drop table #tbl1
end
```